# Run "Double Commander" or any other alternative from SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh

Is there any commander like "Double Commander" which GUI could be executed/loaded/run from SSH connection nor Desktop UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s [Midnight Commander](https://midnight-commander.org/), which runs inside a terminal and works very well over SSH. It’s packaged in most distributions, usually as `mc`; for example in Debian distributions, you can install it with

```
sudo apt install mc
```

If you have a local X server, and forward your X connection (`ssh -X` or `ssh -Y`, or the corresponding options with PuTTY), you can run any X-based file manager, including Double Commander. The file manager you use has to be installed on the remote system.

Many file managers, [“orthodox” file managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_manager#Orthodox_file_managers) in particular, also support directly accessing remote resources over SSH, so you could use that instead (although if your intention is to perform many operations from one directory of the remote system to another directory of the same remote system, it would be more efficient to run the whole file manager remotely).

Comment: Nice! Midnight Commander helped me with transferring files from a RaspberryPi to a router via SFTP, when setting up VPN, for example. Just in case, on Raspberry Pi:
[code]sudo apt-get install mc[/code]

Answer (score 0):

If you need connect Double Commander via SSH

1. Right click on the folder path, at the top of a panel, in my case it is `/home`
   [image]
2. Enter something like `ssh://yourservername@192.168.0.13`